# Whitespace in preformatted blocks not shown on mobile

Tags: bug, markdown, ios-app, mobile-web, code-formatting

I posted [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358157/4751173) today, containing some preformatted text to function as headers for two side by side images.

`WITHOUT RULE                         WITH RULE`

<sub>I know this is not the intended use of code formatting. Please ignore that for the moment.</sub>

This <s>looks fine</s> works as intended when viewing from a browser:

[image]

However, both in the Stack Exchange iOS app and on Safari on iOS, the whitespace is ignored:

[image] [image]